# LotionJS Peer Discovery | Address [...] does not contain ID

Tags: tendermint, lotionjs

I tried to start a network with docker-compose. There I'll pass the ip-address and port number to LotionJS. If i start the docker containers i get an error: 
`Address (x.x.x.x:xxx) does not contain ID`.

But in the LotionJS readme is noted

> peers: [], // array of ':' of initial tendermint nodes to connect to. does automatic peer discovery if not specified.`

So my questions now:

- Do I need the ID?
- If yes, how can I set the ID for a peer?
- Also it seems, that the automatic peer discovery doesn't work?

Comment: Formatting for better readability